# Modify all CSV files in one directory and save modified CSV files in other directory in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to get every single .CSV file from `csvinput` directory, format and modify it and save in `csvoutput` directory, then delete processed files from input folder. The problem is that when there is only one file in input folder, output .CSV file is as it's expected, but when there is two or more files, only first output .CSV file is formatted as expected and others have some unwanted data left and other lines filled.

I'm running `foreach` loop to irritate through .csv files and process them. Here is my complete code for that.

```
<?php

$inputfiles = glob("csvinput/*.csv");
$skip = true;

foreach($inputfiles as $inputfile) {
    if (($input = fopen($inputfile, "r")) !== false) {
        if (($output = fopen('csvoutput/OUTPUT_'.basename($inputfile), 'w')) !== false) {
            $headers = array("Product Code", "Ship Direct Flag", "Delivery Flash", "WEB Price", "WP Promo Price", "GS Promo Price", "Stock Level", "Stock Promise Date", "DROPPEDLINE");
            fputcsv($output, $headers);

            while(($data = fgetcsv($input))) {
                if ($skip) { $skip = false; continue; }
                if (array_filter($data)) {

                    $available_for_sales = $data[0];
                    $code = $data[1];
                    $buying_price = $data[7];
                    $stock_level = $data[13]; 

                    $data[0] = 'DS-'.$code;
                    $data[1] = 'STOCKED';
                    $data[2] = '';
                    $data[3] = $buying_price;
                    $data[4] = $buying_price;
                    $data[5] = $buying_price;
                    $data[6] = $stock_level;
                    $data[7] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("tomorrow"));
                    $data[8] = strtr($available_for_sales,array("1" => "N","0" => "Y"));
                }

                fputcsv($output, array_slice($data, 0, 9)); 
            }

            fclose( $input );
            fclose( $output );

            unlink($inputfile);

            echo 'Successfully processed <b>' .basename($inputfile). '</b><br>';
        } else {
            echo "Could not create file: OUTPUT_".basename($inputfile);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Could not open file: " .basename($inputfile);
    }
}

?>
```

My input files looks like this:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oR34.png)

Expected output files should look like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYK1R.png)

But if there is more than one input file, then all other output files except first look like this:
[uglyoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcyrd.png)

Comment: I may be missing something, but what does that `array_filter()` do for you?

Comment: You are not setting `$skip = true;` before starting the second iteration. So add a `$skip = true;` just before the `}` that closes for foreach loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you very much for showing me the reason for my problem. I set `$skip = true;` right after the `foreach` loop opening curly brace and it woks as intended. 

I want every second row to be empty in output files as it is in input files, so `array_filter()` is preventing empty lines to be filled.